# How to sort nested set elements by rating of root element?

Tags: sql, postgresql, nested-sets

Tree comment system implemented as simple nested set

```
+---------+-----------+---------+---------+-------+--------+
| id      | parent_id | lft     | rgt     | depth | rating |
+---------+-----------+---------+---------+-------+--------+
| 4073406 |           | 1058655 | 1058656 | 0     | 0      |
| 3721850 |           | 1058651 | 1058654 | 0     | 2      |
| 4279470 | 3721850   | 1058652 | 1058653 | 1     | 0      |
| 3682985 |           | 1058649 | 1058650 | 0     | 1      |
| 3643602 |           | 1058647 | 1058648 | 0     | 0      |
| 3182010 |           | 1058643 | 1058646 | 0     | 3      |
+---------+-----------+---------+---------+-------+--------+
```

**Sorting by left and right key**

```
SELECT * FROM COMMENTS ORDER BY rgt DESC; # firstly new
SELECT * FROM COMMENTS ORDER BY lft ASC;  # firstly old
```

That's easy and effectively.

Q: How to sort comments by rating of first [root] comment in thread, and by left or right key for others non root comments?

*A similar implementation you can see on YouTube and some others web sites where you can display **new** or **popular** comments*

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Postgresql? Don't tag products not involved.

Comment: I'm using postgresql

Answer (score 1):

I think this would work if your comments are only two levels deep...  but is it possible for them to be more than two deep?

```
with recursive cte as (
  select
    id, parent_id, lft, rgt, depth, rating,
    rgt * 1.0 as sort_order
  from comments
  where depth = 0

  union all

  select
    c.id, c.parent_id, c.lft, c.rgt, c.depth, c.rating,
    cte.rgt + 0.001 * c.depth
  from
    comments c
    join cte on
      c.parent_id = cte.id
  where
    c.depth != 0
)
select * from cte
order by sort_order
```

-- EDIT 11/28/2017 --

I think this code will handle multiple levels.  Try it and let me know.

```
with recursive cte as (
  select
    id, parent_id, lft, rgt, depth, rating,
    rgt as sort_order1, id::text as sort_order2
  from comments
  where depth = 0

  union all

  select
    c.id, c.parent_id, c.lft, c.rgt, c.depth, c.rating,
    cte.rgt, cte.sort_order2 || ':' || c.id
  from
    comments c
    join cte on
      c.parent_id = cte.id
  where
    c.depth != 0
)
select
  id, parent_id, lft, rgt, depth, rating
from cte
order by sort_order1, sort_order2
```

Comment: It can be 2 and more levels ;(

Comment: @DimaMelnik -- I made a change I think (hope) might help

Comment: Thank you! You idea to use recursive was very useful for me! I have solved my problem with a very little correction of your SQL query from 11/28/2017.

Comment: As sort_order I was using just simple `rating`

Answer (score 0):

The correct SQL query is (pretty close to Hambones answer)

```
WITH RECURSIVE r AS (
            SELECT c1.*, rgt AS _rgt, cached_votes_score AS rating
                FROM comments AS c1
                WHERE 
                    depth = 0 AND
            UNION ALL 
            SELECT c2.*, c2.rgt, rating AS rating
                FROM comments c2
                JOIN r ON c2.parent_id = r.id
        )
        SELECT * FROM r ORDER BY rating desc, _rgt DESC
```